# ¿Como darle transition a linear-gradient?

Tags: css, css3

Como puedo hacer funcionar el `transition` al ejemplo **1** que tiene el color hecho con `linear-gradient`, como el ejemplo **2** que tiene un color solido.

Si es posible, solo en **`CSS`**

```css
.e1 {
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  background: linear-gradient(#400080, transparent), linear-gradient(200deg, #d047d1, #f00, #ff0);
  transition: background .5s ease-in-out;
}

.e1:hover {  
  background: linear-gradient(#2d0059, transparent), linear-gradient(200deg, #a739a8, #b00000, #b5b500);
}

.e2 {
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  background: red;
  transition: background .5s ease-in-out;
}

.e2:hover {  
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
Ejemplo 1
<div class="e1"></div>
<br>
Ejemplo 2
<div class="e2"></div>
```

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que quieres conseguir, quitar el linear-gradient y obtener un color sólido?

Comment: No... _¿Como darle transition a linear-gradient?_

Comment: @PabloLozano - Si pasas con el ratón encima del ejemplo 1 quiero que se comporte igual al ejemplo 2... con transition

Comment: Entendido ahora...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

De momento linear-gradient no admite transitions, pero puedes simular algo similar moviendo el fondo. Lo que tienes aquí es ambos gradiente unidos (linea-gradient acepta todos los parámetros que quieras) y lo que se hace es mostrar la primera mitad o la segunda, transicionando la posición del fondo (background)

```css
div#example1 {
    background-image: linear-gradient(200deg, #d047d1, #f00, #ff0, #a739a8, #b00000, #b5b500);
    background-size: auto 210%;
    background-position: 0 100%;
    transition: background-position 0.5s;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
  
    /* ...and various other button styles */
}

div#example1:hover {
    background-position: 0 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="example1"></div>
```

La otra solución es tener dos div, uno encima(o dentro) de otro, y cambiar la transparencia del que esté encima (o dentro) para transicionar entre totalmente transparente y totalmente opaco, teniendo cada div un linear gradient distinto, pero complica más el añadir texto u otros elementos.

Answer (score 2):

Según he leído [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17952468/css-background-gradient-transition-not-working), no está soportado por CSS, pero se puede simular utilizando la propiedad `opacity`.

```css
.e3 {
    position: relative;
    width: 70px;
    height: 70px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(#400080, transparent), linear-gradient(200deg, #d047d1, #f00, #ff0);
}

.e3:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(#2d0059, transparent), linear-gradient(200deg, #a739a8, #b00000, #b5b500);
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
}

.e3:hover:after {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="e3"></div>
<br>
```